# VBA Consolidating data in shared Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I need to consolidate data from one Excel file to shared Excel either on Sharepoint or OneDrive. Now the problem is with multiple users accessing shared file in the same time. Users are overriting data for each other. I've tried with checking-out the file on Sharepoint, but still users can open it. I've already found that there is couple of ckeckpoints on this process:

1. Check if file can be checked-out and do check-out.
2. If someone already access the file user receive read only notification.
3. Check if file can be checked-in and do check-in with saving.

Although all above points are handled by the code user received message "Export Completed" but consolidation file stays opened and notification po-up that there is new version on the server and if he wants to keep his version or server version. What I'm struggling with is to code choosing version on server and give message to user that consolidation is not possible at the moment. Below is the current code to consolidate on Sharepoint.

```
Sub Consolidation()

//copying data to Array//
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("File Name") Then
   Workbooks.Checkout("File Name")
   Workbooks.Open Filename:="File name", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
       //pasting data in consolidation file//
          If ActiveWorkbook.CanCheckIn = True Then
             ActiveWorkbook.CheckIn (True)
             ActiveWorkbook.Close
             MsgBox("Export Completed")
          Else
             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             ActiveWorkbook.Close
             MsgBox("Someone is exporting now, please try in a moment")
          End If
    Else
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       MsgBox("Someone is exporting now, please try in a moment")
    End If
Else
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    MsgBox("Someone is exporting now, please try in a moment")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How is your data structured? Does each user add a new line? Then you could change your concept => save your data to an access file and load updates from there!

Comment: Why don't you use a Google Sheet?

Comment: Why don't you use a [sharepoint list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083) and then retrieve the results to excel/access as needed? This way all users may update as they need to. You just need to set the connection once and then hit refresh whenever you need to query the results. If you are unable to do so because of how data works (non as linear) then the sugestion by @simple-solution it's the way to go: have a middle-man file that updates the master.